# Binding to AvalonDock ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, resize, avalondock

As described in the title I use AvalonDock in combination with .NET WPF.

My problem:
In my WPF Window I have:

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" DocumentClosing="DocumentClosingEvent" >
        <ad:ResizingPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            .
            .
            .
            <Border Name="Detail_Container"
                    ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="{Binding DetailWidth}">
                <ad:DocumentPane HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <!--Show the Documents-->
                </ad:DocumentPane>
            </Border>
        </ad:ResizingPanel>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

In my ViedModel I implemented a attribute (DetailWidth) for the ResizeWidth. I need this because when there is no Document in the DockingManager the width is 0. If a new Document is opened/added the Size is set to 1000, if all documents are closed the width again is 0.

This works perfectly fine!

The problem now is if the user resizes the width the binding somehow is ignored and the panel stays the same width.

How can I fix this?

Sorry if my english is not that good :)

Comment: Did you try to set the Mode of Binding to TwoWay?

Comment: If I set the Mode to TwoWay the Binding to "DetailWidth" is somehow completely ignored.